# Is a finite cover of Kähler manifold again Kähler?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

It is obvious that a branched finite cover of projective variety is projective. But I don’t see whether it is true that a smooth branched cover of Kähler manifold is Kähler.

Comment: This might depend on the exact meaning of a "branched cover". But if the ramification set of $Y\to X$ is a (possibly disconnected) complex submanifold, then, I think, you can find a Kahler metric on $X$ by using the construction described in section 5 of the paper by Mostow and Siu (Annals of Math. 1980).

Comment: Thanks. The case that I am interesting in is ramified over a normal crossing divisor. I definitely will check that paper out.